# Convert cell arrays of cell array to list in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, cell-array

I have a cell array of cell arrays of strings in matlab. I want to convert this to a simple list of unique strings so that I can access a string by its index in the list. What is the fastest way to do this?
Example -

```
C = {1x3 cell}    {1x2 cell}
>> C{1}
ans = 'What's'    'up'    'man'
>> C{2}
ans = 'What's'    'there'
```

And I want a list of size 4 such that each index refers to a unique word -  'What's', 'up', 'man', 'there'. Not sure if this list should be cell array or matrix or what for it to be most efficient.

Comment: Can you give an example of what your data looks like and what you want it to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code to do what you need. You can use it for any size of array.

```
Cunq = unique(horzcat(C{:}),'stable');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call [union](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/union.html#btcme1d-13) on the cell arrays.

```
union(C{1},C{2})
```

If the order matters, add a third parameter:

```
union(C{1},C{2},'stable')
```